# Chef Server 12 - forgot password links all have localhost instead of the FQDN

Tags: chef-infra

When I test the forgot password functionality I get a link like this:

```
 http://localhost/password-reset?expires=1234567890&signature=1234567890&username=testuser
```

If I change the link manually like this `http://mychefserver.domain.com/password-reset?expires=1234567890&signature=1234567890&username=testuser`, it works just fine.

I've been trying to find a setting somewhere to set this but I can't find anything in docs. I found something that says I have to create a `chef-server.rb` file in `/etc/opscode` but I don't see any setting that would change the above localhost to my fqdn.

Comment: What about `nginx['server_name']`? 
  https://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_chef_server_optional_settings.html